# What is the green substance on C3PO when Jabba the Hutt hits him while bargaining with Boushh?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, c-3po

In Return of the Jedi, [Boushh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boushh) (Princess Leia) brings [Chewbacca](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca) as a bounty to trade for the life of Han Solo.

C3PO is acting as the translator for Jabba. When Boushh is making demands for more money, after C3PO tell Jabba how much, Jabba [hits C3PO with the back of his arm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B28fQ-0LaU&feature=youtu.be&t=1m11s). When he returns he has a green substance on his chest which obviously came from Jabba's arm.

[image]

**What was this green goo supposed to be?**

- Blood?
- Pus?
- Sweat?
- Something else?

I really can't see it being blood, as Jabba was not injured as far as I can see. So is there any canon information on what the green substance was?

Comment: Given the size of Jabba's nostrils, it's most probably the snot that he's wiped onto the back of his forearm.

Comment: @Pete, if there is something says it is snot, make it an answer, I am not against snot in any way.

Comment: I don't have a ready reference to the Canon database, so I made this as a comment.  If I did supply this as an answer, it would invariably be down-voted for not being a Canon answer.

Comment: I assumed it was slime, because he's a big slug thing.

Comment: Just a jot of Jabba-juice

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It appears to be whatever Jabba was drinking. He certainly seems to spill plenty of it in the following scene.

> Belowdecks, in a dark and nasty hold, Jabba is in high spirits.
>
> Today it will be great fun to watch his enemies plead for their lives
> before being dropped into the Sarlacc’s gaping mouth. And tomorrow the
> story of his triumph will spread across the planet…and then the
> galaxy.
>
> **Drooling with the pleasure of it all, he gulps down a glassful of
> thick, green liquid.** It’s strong stuff and half this much would kill a
> lesser creature, but it merely intoxicates Jabba.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Return of the Jedi - Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 21):

The script is silent on it other than C3-PO being "disheveled".

> Jabba immediately flies into a rage, knocking the golden droid off the 
>   raised throne into a clattering heap on the floor. Boushh adjusts his 
>   weapon as Jabba raves in Huttese and Threepio struggles back onto the 
>   throne. The disheveled droid tries to compose himself.

The Official Novelisation doesn't even refer to Jabba's arm but rather his tail.

> Threepio quietly translated for Jabba, who immediately became enraged and knocked the golden droid off the raised throne with a sweep of his massive tail. Threepio clattered in a heap on the floor, where he rested momentarily, uncertain of the correct protocol in this situation.

So, we don't know but apparently it's not from Jabba's arm.

Here's the image of C3-PO just **after** he's hit. There's nothing on his chest **or face**. *Note that he wasn't hit on the face but when he get back up he does have green goo on it.*

[image]

It seems likely that, whatever it was, he picked it up when he landed on the floor.

Here he can be seen with goo in three places

[image]

Comment: It was from Jabba, the special effects at the time was not able to keep up with real time.

Comment: It is exactly where he was hit.

Comment: He wasn't hit on the face but there's goo on it.

Comment: Good call!!!!!!

Comment: Considering that Hutts are based off of slugs, it's not unreasonable to assume that it's one of the two kinds of mucus (specifically the thick and sticky kind, by the lookds of it) from Jabba's slime trail.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is: When Jabba reached into that bowl of fluid to grab that creature he then ate, there was some slime - possibly algae - in the bowl, and it got on Jabba's hand, and from there onto C3P0.

*[I -think- Jabba ate the creature before that negotiation; but if not, there's no reason not to conjecture that he ate another one earlier]*

Comment: @Angew: You can see him eating the thing right at the beginning of the video (with his left hand). I doubt his right hand would have reached! :)

Answer (score 4):

[image: See-Threepio covered in slime]

It looks like whatever the green slime is it’s the contents of some sort of fruit that he landed in when Jabba pushed him.

Comment: source of this image? Don't think I've seen it before